# h:commandLink and onclick Javascript function

Tags: jsf, seam

I have the following peace of code:

```
<DIV>
    <h:commandLink action="#{documentGen.generatePDF}"
        target="_blank"
        onclick="return checkSelected();">
        <h:graphicImage url="/images/pdf.jpg"
        styleClass="pdfimage" title="Click to show PDF"></h:graphicImage>
    </h:commandLink>
</DIV>
```

This above is placed in a table, where user can tick checkboxes and click the above commandLink which is to meant to open up a new window and display the content generated by the backbean   `#{documentGen.generatePDF}`.

This works as expected if i **DON'T** include `onclick="return checkSelected();"`. IF i include it then the backbean is never called, instead i get new window which is a duplicate of the current.

I need this javascript function to check user has at least checked 1 checkbox and otherwise display alert. The Javascript function works fine and i see the alert if no checkbox is ticked when the commandLink is click.

My question is, why does it `onclick` line mess up what commandLink does? What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

The `h:commandLink` is inside `h:form`.  As mentioned the above command link works as expected WITHOUT the `onclick=....`.

To test i changed the javascript function called on onclick to:

```
function testFunc() {
        alert("GOT Here!")
        return ture;
 }
```

and in the commandlink on click to :  `onclick="return testFunc();"`

Result is i get the alert "GOT Here!" but as before, the new window is duplicate of current window and backbean doesn't get called. Removing the onclick line corrects the outcome (but need the javascript function there to check for checked checkboxes).

In browser source view the difference between the commandlink without onclik and with onclick is as below:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="return oamSubmitForm('genView','genView:_idJsp33','_blank',[]);" id="genView:_idJsp33" target="_blank"><img src="/images/pdf.jpg" title="Click for Pdf Document" class="pdfimage"></a>


  <a href="#" onclick="return testFunc();;return oamSubmitForm('genView','genView:_idJsp33','_blank',[]);" id="genView:_idJsp33" target="_blank"><img src="/images/pdf.jpg" title="Click for Pdf Document" class="pdfimage"></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are always returning. I think what you want is only return false if necessary and continue otherwise.

So change your onclick to

`onclick="if (checkSelected()) { return false; }"`

This is for sure an issue with Ajax submitted forms, because the submit is never called if you return before. I can imagine that this counts for **standard** form submits too.

Comment: THank you so much, You were spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If you return false in the onclick event of a commandLink, the form won't be submitted